# Dilemma... Which Program & Language to develop my Android and iOS App

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, ios, cordova

I'm developing an app for both the android and ios platform. I'd like to take a route that allows me to only have to code once for both platforms. There are 2 options I've come across:

- Develop in Flash builder 4.5 with flex (actionscript, or I've heard javascript also?)
- Develop using Phonegap (javascript)

The app is very simple - it will use the google api and the phone's geolocation function, then also display more information about the business listings from google map's api. Downloaders of the app will also have to register to become free members. All of this information will have to be put into a mysql database on my server.

So my question is, which is the best route to take with what I am hoping to accomplish? If using Flash builder, is it best to learn actionscript or javascript? What's the best way to connect with the mysql server if I'm writing in javascript, ajax?

Answer (score 2):

If you are serious about it and want to create other apps as well in the future, you should learn the native frameworks/languages for each of the platforms. If not, and you just want to make one quick app I would choose Phonegap rather than Flex/Flash.

Comment: Phonegap + flex, does such an hybrid abomination actually exist? LOL.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I meant that I would use Phonegap rather than Flex, not both :)

Comment: OK, I'm a bit outdated in the last "magic button" programming tendencies, so you never know. I would use assembly code if available XD.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, get familiar with HTML and Javascript to understand what they are even capable of. There's no point in trying to complete a project with tools that you don't understand. As for the options you named, I'd definitely go with the Phonegap method as it is much simpler.

However, you also need a backend for your solution if you're trying to use a MySQL or other database to store any data. For this you'd need some server-side language like PHP, JSP (or you could use NodeJS, if you want Javscript on the server too) etc, that retrieves information from the database according to the requests received from your app.

In conclusion, I'd suggest you to read more about PHP/MySQL, Javascript and making webpages, since this is what you are actually trying to do if you use Phonegap, even though you might look it as an app. Do some tutorials, get to know the languages before you try to take on something that surpasses your skill level just yet.

Answer (score 1):

For a nice small db-interface I'd rather suggest using ruby (with sinatra as mvc-framework and activerecord on top of mysql, or just use rails) than using php!

http://guides.rubyonrails.org

http://www.sinatrarb.com/